# Reading from two excel and creating difference file

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

Reading from two excel files and writing the differences into another excel file. It is showing the differences but not at the right index. It is not writing "Correct" at the appropriate position. Please tell me how it can be fixed
This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


   def report_diff(x):
    if x[0] == x[1]:
         return 'Correct'
    else:
         return '{} ---> {}'.format(*x)

def has_change(row):
if "--->" in row.to_string():
    return "Y"
else:
    return "N"

df1 = pd.read_excel(r'File1.xlsx', 'Sheet1', na_values=['NA']) df2 =
pd.read_excel(r'File2.xlsx', 'Sheet1', na_values=['NA'])

df = pd.read_excel(r'File1.xlsx') writer =
pd.ExcelWriter('Differences.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Highlighting-Error',index=False)

diff_panel = pd.Panel(dict(df1=df1,df2=df2))

diff_output = diff_panel.apply(report_diff, axis=0)

diff_output['has_change'] = diff_output.apply(has_change, axis=1)


diff_output[(diff_output.has_change ==
'Y')].to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Difference-Sheet',index=False,
                                                columns["dbsymbol","alias"])

writer.save()
```

data:

```
dbSymbol    Alias
UQ_121      mike
UQ142       Sam
UQ143       john
UQ144       deep
UQ145      shubh
UQ_121      joe
UQ_121      name

dbSymbol    Alias
UQ_121      mike
UQ142       sammy
UQ143       johnny
UQ144           deep
UQ145           shubh
UQ_121        Ann

Output: 
dbSymbol    Alias
UQ_121      mike
UQ142       Sam---> Sammy
UQ143       john--->Johnny
UQ144       deep
UQ145      shubh
UQ_121        Ann--->mike
UQ_121     shubh-->mike
UQ_121     name-->mike
```

Comment: Can you create some sample data and post to question? I think [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is it enough? @jezrael

Comment: Yes, it is OK. But one question - df1 and df2 have always same number of rows?

Comment: Yes. It has same number of rows @jezrael

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution should be simplify [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and for `False`s values of boolean mask join both `DataFrames` with `--->`:

```
mask = df1 == df2
diff_output = df1.where(mask, df1.astype(str) + ' ---> ' + df2.astype(str))
print (diff_output)
  dbSymbol             Alias
0   UQ_121              mike
1    UQ142    Sam ---> sammy
2    UQ143  john ---> johnny
3    UQ144              deep
4    UQ145             shubh
```

**Detail**:

```
print (mask)
   dbSymbol  Alias
0      True   True
1      True  False
2      True  False
3      True   True
4      True   True
```

EDIT: If different length of DataFrames with duplicates is possible use:

```
print (df1)
  dbSymbol  Alias
0   UQ_121   mike
1    UQ142    Sam
2    UQ143   john
3    UQ144   deep
4    UQ145  shubh
5   UQ_121    joe
6   UQ_121   name

print (df2)
  dbSymbol   Alias
0   UQ_121    mike
1    UQ142   sammy
2    UQ143  johnny
3    UQ144    deep
4    UQ145   shubh
5   UQ_121     Ann
```

---

```
df1['count'] = df1.groupby('dbSymbol').cumcount()
df2['count'] = df2.groupby('dbSymbol').cumcount()
df1 = df1.set_index(['count','dbSymbol'])
df2 = df2.set_index(['count','dbSymbol'])
df1, df2 = df1.align(df2)
df1 = df1.fillna('').reset_index()
df2 = df2.fillna('').reset_index()
```

---

```
print (df1)
   count dbSymbol  Alias
0      0    UQ142    Sam
1      0    UQ143   john
2      0    UQ144   deep
3      0    UQ145  shubh
4      0   UQ_121   mike
5      1   UQ_121    joe
6      2   UQ_121   name

print (df2)
   count dbSymbol   Alias
0      0    UQ142   sammy
1      0    UQ143  johnny
2      0    UQ144    deep
3      0    UQ145   shubh
4      0   UQ_121    mike
5      1   UQ_121     Ann
6      2   UQ_121        

mask = df1 == df2
diff_output = df1.where(mask, df1.astype(str) + ' ---> ' + df2.astype(str))
print (diff_output)
   count dbSymbol             Alias
0      0    UQ142    Sam ---> sammy
1      0    UQ143  john ---> johnny
2      0    UQ144              deep
3      0    UQ145             shubh
4      0   UQ_121              mike
5      1   UQ_121      joe ---> Ann
6      2   UQ_121        name --->
```

Comment: Actually it does not have equal number of rows @jezrael

Comment: @deep5459 - hmmm, `dbSymbol` values are unique in both excel files?

Comment: No , there can be multiple entries for same dbsymbol @jezrael

Comment: @deep5459 - OK, there are multiple columns? Or always only `dbSymbol` and `Alias` ?

Comment: There are total multiple columns @jezrael

Comment: Thank you. So if there are multiple symbols, is possible change input data, e.g. add more rows like `UQ_121 joe`, `UQ_121 ann` to first data. Second data should be added `UQ_121 ann`. Then is necessary add expected output. Can you do it?

Comment: Because there should be this approaches - check first duplicate row with first row in second data, second duplicate row with second... Is it possible?

Comment: @deep5459 - OK, but what happen if duplicates in both ? E.g added `UQ_121      joe` to first data? Do you want check all combination of dupes?

Comment: No just the first  UQ_121  ->  mike will be correct else will be shown like Ann--->mike  @jezrael

Comment: @deep5459 - I edit your question, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51960760/revisions). Can you add expected output?

Comment: @deep5459 - I add more rows to data - duplicates rows with `UQ_121`. So problem is your real data have no structire like edited - duplicates values like `UQ_121` for data1 and data2?

Comment: @deep5459 - Question is - There are duplicates `dbSymbol` values in both data?

Comment: Yes there are duplicates  @jezrael

Comment: @deep5459 - OK, so added more sample data to data1, chec last 2 rows. Can you create exoected output with comparing data1 and data2 ?

Comment: I have added the output @jezrael

Comment: @deep5459 - Unfortunately not understand your output, can you check solution in edited answer?

Comment: Sorry for providing wrong information, Actually  for every dbSymbol there will be only one alias , so no duplicates will be there. So, for  "UQ_121" there will be alias name "mike" will be there .@jezrael

Comment: @deep5459 - So if change `df1 = df1.set_index(['count','dbSymbol'])
df2 = df2.set_index(['count','dbSymbol'])` to `df1 = df1.set_index(['dbSymbol'])
df2 = df2.set_index(['dbSymbol'])` it working?

Comment: where to change , I haven't use set_index  @jezrael

Comment: @check 3. and 4.row in my second solution.

Comment: Ok , Let me check @jezrael